# Is there any method to remove the driver file and uninstall the device in UWP applications?

Tags: windows, uwp, driver

Previously, when I need to uninstall a device. I can

1. use devcon tool to realize. Use "devcon.exe drivernodes " to find the inf driver file. Then use "devcon.exe dp_delete " to delete the driver and use "devcon.exe remove " to remove the device.
2. use SetupAPI to write a program to realize. Functions  "SetupDiEnumDriverInfo", "SetupUninstallOEMInf" and SetupDiCallClassInstaller" with param "DIF_REMOVE" can realize this requirement.

But when I convert my application to UWP, I find that devcon tool can't be used any more as it doesn't match UWP requirement. And there is no replaced functions for above SetupAPI functions.

This makes me puzzled.
Is there any method to remove the driver file and uninstall the device in UWP applications?

Answer (score 1):

Removing a driver/device is an elevated operation. This kind of operation is not allowed for UWP applications by design. UWP apps are intended to be user mode apps that execute with the user's privileges, not system software that executes with admin privileges.

What is your scenario?

Comment: My application will run as a service. Used to install/uninstall the driver for a special device, update firmware of this device and monitor the running status of this device. It is not a UI application, but an application for drivers.

Comment: UWP apps cannot run as a Windows service, they need to be able to run as user without elevation.

Comment: Maybe something wrong in my question. I need to develop a WindowsApplicationForDrivers10.0 which should follow the target platform of "Universal". And it will run as a service. Actually, it will only run in laptops.